# jooq RecordListener never catch updateEnd and updateStart event

Tags: java, jooq, audit

Using JOOQ 3.9.6 I tried to implement a record listener like this :

```
public class AuditListener extends DefaultRecordListener {

    ....

    @Override
    public void insertEnd(RecordContext ctx) {
        // OK we enter here when inserting a record
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void updateEnd(RecordContext ctx) {
        // never enter this method when we update a record
    }
}
```

We update a record via DSLContext using update(...) and execute() of the update. The updateEnd event is never caught by AuditListener.

Here is the repository used to update the record :

```
@Component
public class JooqMyentityRepository extends AbstractJooqRespository<MyentityRecord, Myentity> implements MyentityRepository {

    public JooqMyentityRepository() {
        super(Myentity.class, MYENTITY);
    }

    @Override
    public Myentity findById(Integer myentityId) {
        return dsl.select(MYENTITY.fields()).from(MYENTITY).where(MYENTITY.ID.eq((myentityId))).fetchOneInto(Myentity.class);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void update(Myentity myentity) {
        dsl.update(MYENTITY)
            .set(MYENTITY.NAME, myentity.getName())
            .set(MYENTITY.AREA_ID, myentity.getAreaId())
            .set(MYENTITY.ACTIVE, myentity.getActive())
            .set(MYENTITY.BRAND, myentity.getBrand())
            .where(MYENTITY.ID.eq(myentity.getId()))
            .execute();

    }
}
```

The repository is called in a custom service :

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "singleton")
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private MyentityRepository myentityRepository;


    public void editCustomerMyentity(CustomerMyentity customerMyentity){

        Myentity myentity = myentityRepository.findbyId(customerMyentity.getId());
        ...
        // Do treatments here : insert another record to trace the modification
        ...
        myentity.setName(customerMyentity.getName());
        myentity.setBrand(customerMyentity.getBrand());
        myentityRepository.update(myentity);

    }
}
```

Is this an issue or am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you show the code of your `update()` call?

Comment: @LukasEder I've added code, if you need more information you can ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`RecordListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/RecordListener.html) SPI Javadoc states that it intercepts calls to methods like [`UpdatableRecord.update()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/UpdatableRecord.html#update--).

It cannot intercept arbitrary update calls, e.g. `DSLContext.update()` or even `DSLContext.execute("UPDATE ..")` because jOOQ wouldn't know for sure how many and which records are going to be affected by the update statement in the database. In addition to that, there is not actual `UpdatableRecord` involved in the lifecycle of a `DSLContext.update()` statement as in your service, so what kind of SPI call to `updateEnd()` would you expect?

Comment: perfect, I'm new to JOOQ and I'm working on an existing application, then I wasn't aware that there was another way to update a record. Now it comes very clear to my eyes, thank you Lukas